# Custom Error Message for API call failure or API down in AD B2C Custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm integrating a rest API for validation of a field in custom policy. If my API is down it is showing a message by default, but that is not user friendly. Is there any way to customise the error message. I'm following this documentation for rest API integration
[Rest API integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw)

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>REST APIs</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>

    <!-- Custom Restful service -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-SignUp">
      <DisplayName>Validate user's input data and return loyaltyNumber claim</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://your-app-name.azurewebsites.NET/api/identity/signup</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
        <!-- REMOVE the following line in production environments -->
        <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="firstName" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="lastName" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="loyaltyNumber" PartnerClaimType="loyaltyNumber" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>

    <!-- Change LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail technical profile to support your validation technical profile -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="loyaltyNumber" PartnerClaimType="loyaltyNumber" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-API-SignUp" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Comment: A similar question: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/39932. You can catch the error codes at app level and redirect based on the value.

Comment: But i tried the code, in my policy i added a wrong URL and tested, but i got the default error message in the UI. It doesn't came back to the application.

Message: "The claims exchange 'testexchange' specified in step '1' returned HTTP error response with Code 'NotFound' and Reason 'Not Found'."

Comment: @AllenWu But if it is an error like Custom UI CORS issue, then it comes to the code, here:
https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet-SUSI/blob/0d7534eb768954a5c383c4508036d6a871d22354/WebApp-B2C-DotNet/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L49